# Default report paramter value in SSRS 2012

Tags: reporting-services

I am receiving the following error from my child report: "The report parameter 'prmDefaultValueForSnapShots' has a value of DefaultValue or a ValidValue that depends on the report parameter 'prmStoreName'. Forward dependencies are not valid."

I have a parent report that feed values to the child report to display all sales data for the specific store. However, this report is rather large, thus I'm trying to set a snapshot for it on the Report Manager to execute in the early mornings for better user experience. For the snapshot to work, I need a default value on the parameter and I have been unable to make it work.

If anyone has any idea how to resolve this particular issue. Please, give me any suggestion as you can.

Regards,

Marcus

I have been researching this issue since Tuesday and I have not had any luck.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your goal or configuration. I'm also not sure if `prmDefaultValueForSnapShots` and `prmStoreName` are parameters of the main report or the sub-reports, and which of the two throws the error.

However, this error may occur if a parameter depends on another parameter which is not yet provided. Note that the **order** of the parameters **is important**. By "order", I mean the order in which they are defined, which is also the order in which they appear in the list (you can reorder them using the arrow buttons).
Is it possible that `prmDefaultValueForSnapShots` depends on `prmStoreName`, but is defined before it?

Comment: Sorry, let's try again. I need the child report to be a saved as a snapshot in Report Manager. Both of these parameters are on the child report. One parameter, which is the prmStoreName takes a value from the parent and filters that data to whatever the value from the parent was. The second parameter, prmDefaultValueForSnaphots are to set a default value so I can create a snapshot.

Comment: Can you post the definitions of the parameter datasets that provide available values for prmStoreName  and prmDefaultValueForSnaphots? @OB3 is suggesting that the dataset for prmDefaultValueForSnaphots relies on the value selected in prmStoreName.